# In python, does `@=` act on the left or the right?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

It seems obvious to me that `vector @= matrix` ought to mean `vector = matrix @ vector`, contrary to the practice with most other binary operators. Unfortunately, any discussion of this is completely omitted from [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/); it states only that the `@` operator is left-associative, and that the `@=` operator corresponds to the `__imatmul__` function.

Presumably, the override means that numerical libraries can choose this behavior if they like, but that leaves three closely related question:

- What is the default behavior if `__imatmul__` is not explicitly provided, but `__matmul__` and `__rmatmul__` are?
- What is the behavior intended by the authors of the PEP?
- What behavior have numerical libraries such as numpy chosen to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other augmented assignment operator, `x @= y` is an in-place-if-`x`-supports-it version of `x = x @ y`.

`x = y @ x` might have seemed obvious to you, but I don't think anything other than `x = x @ y` was ever considered a serious option, and I don't think any major math library has implemented anything like what you expected. `sympy.Matrix` implements it as `x = x @ y` (non-mutative, no `__imatmul__`), and `numpy.ndarray` says

```
TypeError: In-place matrix multiplication is not (yet) supported. Use 'a = a @ b' instead of 'a @= b'.
```

(Checked with NumPy 1.19.5 and 1.21.5).

Note that NumPy defines a useful meaning for "vector @ matrix" operations. NumPy does not force arrays to be 2D, so the most common vector representation in NumPy is a 1D array, not a column vector. A 1D array will behave like a row vector in a "vector @ matrix" operation, though the result will be 1D instead of a row vector.

Comment: I find myself hoping that NumPy never implements in-place matrix multiplication, since there's no way to do so that won't be a potential source of bugs and confusing error messages for users who have expectations other than the chosen behavior.